# input field value disappears when I enter the decimal point on the numeric keypad

Tags: html, forms, input, formik

I use a number input field with Formik
which is coded as follows :

```
     <Form.Control
          value={formikProps.values.amount}
          onChange={(evt: any) => {
            formikProps.setFieldValue(
              `formInvoice.amount`,
              parseFloat(evt.target.value)
            );               
          }
         }
          type="number"
          step=".01"
          name="amount"                           
        />
```

When I enter a decimal value with the dot on the numeric keypad my value disappears from the field.

whereas if I use the comma for the decimal there's no problem.

I think it must be a problem with the `parseFloat`

is there a solution?

Comment: If you want to allow both dot and comma _as_ decimal point, then you will have to replace the comma with a dot, before you pass the value to parseFloat.

Comment: I think that's because Formik uses its default validation, `onChange`  when you use `setFieldValue`. 

You need to set `validateOnChange` to `false`  as a third parameter of your `setFieldValue()` call, because it's set to `true` by default, and I think that's what causes the probem. You can check the [Docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--promisevoid--formikerrors) for further details.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript's parseFloat function does not handle comma (,) as a valid character in a numeric string. In JavaScript, commas are not considered a part of the numeric format and are used as thousands separators.

To parse a string with commas as a thousands separator and get a valid number, you need to remove the commas from the string before using parseFloat. You can do something like this:

```js
let stringWithCommas = '29,332.34';
let stringWithoutCommas = stringWithCommas.replace(/,/g, ''); // Remove commas
let parsedNumber = parseFloat(stringWithoutCommas); // Parse the number
console.log(parsedNumber); // This will output 29332.34
```